# how to order data in mysql by join count?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, sorting, join

I have two tables :

```
posts : id,title,content,show,created_at

comments: id,post_id,created_at
```

I'm trying to order posts by most commented.

```
SELECT *, COUNT(comments.id) AS total_comments
FROM comments LEFT JOIN posts ON posts.id = comments.post_id
WHERE posts.show = '1'
GROUP BY complains.id
ORDER BY total_comments DESC
```

The problem is that the posts with 0 comments don't appear.
Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: What are you asking? How to sort a `count`, or why posts with 0 comments are not appearing?

Comment: You need to `LEFT JOIN` comments to posts, not posts to comments. That way, posts with zero comments will show.

Comment: what is complains?  Is that supposed to read comments?

Comment: You ... can't count something that doesn't exist.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With your join above, you are incorrectly joining to get commens that have posts 
You should have done a right join or swap the tables in left join like below.

```
Select *, COUNT(comments.id) as total_comments
FROM posts
LEFT outer JOIN comments on  posts.id = comments.post_id
WHERE posts.show = '1'
GROUP BY posts.id
ORDER BY total_comments DESC
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to do a RIGHT JOIN instead of a LEFT JOIN. Or swap the tables in the LEFT JOIN clause.

Comment: +1 for explaining the problem and NOT writing out the solution for him. Sadly, Nihat just did the homework problem for him without an ounce of explanation.

Comment: I am new as you can see from my profile. I will do better next time. thank you for the comment.

Comment: @Nihat Way to be a man. I feel like a jerk now! We're all here just to help people in the end. I sincerely apologize for my rude comment.

Comment: Hey, you taught me a lesson. You are also right. He wouldn't learn anything if  there were no explanations.

Answer (score 1):

While there are many ways to solve this, I think this code is easy to read and understand.

The query in the LEFT JOIN can be copied out and run on its own to help debug.  Then you join that result set to the posts table and order the results.

```
SELECT p.*, IFNULL(c.total_comments, 0) as total_comments
FROM posts p
LEFT JOIN (select post_id, count(post_id) as total_comments from comments group by post_id) as c ON p.id = c.post_id
WHERE p.show = '1'
ORDER BY c.total_comments DESC
```